# Решено: Обработка события при изменении элемента SysTreeView32

Tags: winapi, delphi

Пытаюсь обработать событие при изменении элемента SysTreeView32:

```
function DlgWndProc(Wnd: HWND; uMsg: Integer;
  wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; Stdcall;
var
//
nm: PNMHDR;
begin
//
Result:=0;
//
  case uMsg of
  //
  WM_NOTIFY:
      begin
      //
      nm:=PNMHDR(lParam);
      //
      if nm^.code = TVN_SELCHANGED then TreeViewProc;
      end;

  //
  WM_CLOSE: DlgWndDestroy;

  //
  WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);

  //
  else Result:=DefWindowProc(Wnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;
```

Но, почему-то, **TVN_SELCHANGED** не принимается.
Как это можно исправить?

**P.S.** Нашёл решение:
у меня **Lazarus** (*1.0.8*), переопределил константу

```
TVN_SELCHANGED: UINT = -(402);
```

и условие

```
nm^.code = TVN_SELCHANGED
```

стало выполняться...

Comment: Должно приходить. Покажи минимальный пример воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: Добавил свой пример кода...

Comment: В неё и не должны приходить сообщения с Wnd = hTreeView. Тебе необходимо ловить сообщение WM_NOTIFY, о чём ты и пишешь в начале вопроса.

Comment: Не обрабатывал еще **WM_NOTIFY**. Если я правильно понял, мне нужно вызвать **BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP**, в нём
**ON_NOTIFY** с **TVN_ITEMCHANGED** и функцией обработки этого события, и завершить **END_MESSAGE_MAP**?

Comment: Я не знаком с Object Pascal, в Си/С++ это делается немного по-другому, но судя по всему да, попробуй так. Попробовать обработать WM_NOTIFY следовало бы в самом начале.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. WM_NOTIFY теперь приходит в оконную процедуру, но как с ним быть, я ещё пока не разобрался...

Answer (score 1):

Обрабатывать сообщения надо в оконной процедуре, а не в цикле обработки сообщений.
У тебя какая-то странная и неправильная оконная процедура (если я правильно её понял на этом языке).

[Пример оконной процедуры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx#designing_proc).

[Цикл обработки сообщений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_loop).

Там примеры на Си, но разобраться не сложно, принцип тот же.

Comment: Мм.. ты не должен вручную вызывать оконную процедуру. Этим занимается функция DispatchMessage в цикле обработки сообщений.

Comment: Я сейчас только заметил, что часть кода не вошла в сообщение, спасибо!